# Errors running builder 'Drools Builder' on project Could not initialize class org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory

Tags: eclipse, ant, jbpm

I am creating a sample Jbpm project by following jbpm official documentation from https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.1.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_jbpminstaller
while the ant start.demo went success, as I move on to create new jBPM Project from Eclipse I get below error-

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Drools Builder' on project 'Demo'.
Could not initialize class org.kie.api.KieServices$Factory
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you found any answer?

Comment: Not yet , I actually moved to some other task